# Generating unique group id based on combination of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

A sample of my dataset looks like this:

```
fact_code line_code date        style   buyer smv
1004      100401    2013-02-02  TS-334  2     7.15 
1004      100401    2013-02-03  TS-334  2     7.15
1008      100801    2013-04-12  SST     8     8.58
1008      100801    2013-04-13  SST     8     8.58
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...
1008      100801    2013-07-31  SST     2     9.20
1008      100801    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ... 
1008      100802    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20
1008      100802    2013-08-02  SST     2     9.20
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...
1008      100802    2013-08-12  SST     2     9.20
```

Variables `fact_code`, `line_code` are factory and line code respectively. `style` is the garment style produced by a given `line_code` on a certain `date` for a given `buyer`.

I aim to create a variable called spell number for each garment  (for eg. T-shirts) style, `spell_num`, that is produced by a factory line. The variable and the data would look something like this:

```
fact_code line_code date        style   buyer smv   spell_num
1004      100401    2013-02-02  TS-334  2     7.15  TS-334_1
1004      100401    2013-02-03  TS-334  2     7.15  TS-334_1
1008      100801    2013-04-12  SST     8     8.58  SST_1
1008      100801    2013-04-13  SST     8     8.58  SST_1
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ...
1008      100801    2013-07-31  SST     2     9.20  SST_1  
1008      100801    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20  SST_1
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ... 
1008      100802    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20  SST_2
1008      100802    2013-08-02  SST     2     9.20  SST_2
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ... 
1008      100802    2013-08-12  SST     2     9.20  SST_2
```

The purpose of the variable, `spell_num` is to indicate the *current spell number of each garment style* that is produced by factory line. So, for example, TS-334_1 indicates first spell of production for the garment style TS-334. Similarly, SST_1 indicates the first spell for the style SST, whereas SST_2 indicates its second spell of production. Therefore, whenever a different line produces a style, it indicates a new spell for that same style. The underscore partitions the style name on its left and spell number/indicator on its right.

To this end, this is the code that I have tried among others:

```
mydf <- mydf %>%
  dplyr::group_by(line_code, style) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(spell_num = paste(style, as.integer(row_number() == 1L), sep = "_"))
```

where `mydf` is the name of the pertinent data frame.

And below is the resultant output:

```
fact_code line_code date        style   buyer smv   spell_num
1004      100401    2013-02-02  TS-334  2     7.15  TS-334_1
1004      100401    2013-02-03  TS-334  2     7.15  TS-334_0
1008      100801    2013-04-12  SST     8     8.58  SST_1
1008      100801    2013-04-13  SST     8     8.58  SST_0
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ...
1008      100801    2013-07-31  SST     2     9.20  SST_0  
1008      100801    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20  SST_0
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ... 
1008      100802    2013-08-01  SST     2     9.20  SST_1
1008      100802    2013-08-02  SST     2     9.20  SST_0
...       ...       ...         ...     ...   ...   ... 
1008      100802    2013-08-12  SST     2     9.20  SST_0
```

As can be seen, the above R code, however, is not yielding the expected values for the variable, `spell_num`. For example, instead of the values SST_1, SST_0,...,SST_0 for style SST produced by line 100801 from 2013-04-13 till 2013-08-01, I want it to be rather SST_1, SST_1,...,SST_1, which shows that the style is currently is in its first spell of production.

The `spell_num` changes to SST_2 i.e. the second spell of production for style SST, when it is produced by a different factory line, for example, 100802.

Therefore, my question is how can I get the expected values for the variable `spell_num` given the above dataset and description?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If a style is produced by line code A, then line code B, then line code A again, do you want the second spell with A to have the same `spell_num` as the first spell with A, or a new `spell_num`? (Or does that not happen in your data)

Comment: No, same ```spell_num``` if produced by the same line code. The data are also arranged by line code. So we should a line code only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% nest(-style, -line_code) %>% 
  group_by(style) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(spell_num = paste(style, index, sep = "_"))
```

Comment: the code is giving me an error message: Error in -style : invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`.

```
setDT(mydf) # convert to data.table
setkey(mydf, style, linecode) # set key to ensure sorting
mydf[, spell_num := paste(style, rleid(line_code), sep = "_"), by = .(style)]
```